# V.2. Chapter 5 - RSpec title test fails with the variable full_title, but passes with string text the variable full_title provides to the title

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, railstutorial.org

I find this question below to be very similar, so I will use the text.The solution didn't work because I don't have (Can't find anywhere) the `spec/support/utilities.rb` I'm with rails 4 (dk if it's relevant) and the `bundle guard` does not run.

I'm going through [Chapter 5 of RailsTutorial.org](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#sec-pretty_rspec).

I have one test that I can't get to work no matter what I do. It passes when I put in the string the variable passes, but not when I put in the variable itself.

The error says **undefined method 'full_title'**

Doing a superficial test, the desired content displays in the app, the title includes the full title with 'Help'

Here is my code:

```
  describe "Help page" do
    before { visit help_path }

    it { should have_content('Help') }
    it { should have_title(full_title('Help')) }
  end
```

This is when the error says **undefined method 'full_title'**

It passes when I use this code:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "Help page" do
    before { visit help_path }

    it { should have_content('Help') }
    it { should have_title("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App") }
  end
```

Thanks for your help!

EDIT : I have defined full_title in application_helper.rb

```
def full_title(page_title)
    base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App" 
        return base_title if page_title.empty? 
        return "#{page_title} | #{base_title}" 
    end
end
```

Comment: What's full_title supposed to do/be?

Comment: full title is supposed to be "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"

Comment: And where/how are you defining this method, and what is the "Help" parameter to it supposed to indicate?

Comment: I really don't know, and I would like to know where do I define it and how do I define it. My only hint on where it is defined is application.html.erb file <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>. Here I just did the old copy paste of the correct code, so I'm trying to figure it out all. Help is the name of the page.

Answer (score 1):

As the [tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#code-rspec_utilities) says, you have to define the method `full_title` in a `.rb` file contained in the `spec/support` directory, because files in the `spec/support` directory are automatically included by RSpec. The author recommends you to create the following method in this file that you have to create `spec/support/utilities.rb`

```
def full_title(page_title)
  base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  if page_title.empty?
    base_title
  else
    "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
  end
end
```

Comment: I already have this, I figure it out 30 seconds ago, and it stills gets me the error.

Comment: BUT, 1) I have that code not there but instead in app/helpers/application_helper.rb don't know why really as I don't know why don't I have that directory on my files, but instead I have spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb and spec/spec_helper.rb

Comment: Try to require this file at the beginning of your spec file. Put this as first line of your test file `require spec/support/utilities`

Comment: @luigi `app/helpers/application_helper` is not the same as `spec/support`. I already explained why this directory is special for the tests. So please, do not say that the above does not work if you are doing another thing (putting in other place this method)

Comment: Result tried with and without .rb: /rails_projects/sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- spec/support/utilities.rb (LoadError)

Comment: Just create the file `spec/support/utilities.rb` with the method `full_title` as I said in my answer.

Comment: I don't have spec/support, should I create one manually? I just said where I did find something that looked like defining a method to me, and the location was in app/helpers/application_helper.rb.

Comment: Now it doesn't even test. Just gets me a handful of errors even if I don't require the utilities.rb, it says that I have a syntax error on the end, put it's well placed and without nothing wrong

Comment: It's still doesn't pass:  

    Failure/Error: it { should have_title(full_title('Help')) }
    expected #has_title?(" Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Help ") to return true, got false


Why don't it return true? Do I need to define page_title to?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this.

create spec/support/utilities.rb

```
def full_title(page_title)
  base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  if page_title.empty?
    base_title
  else
    "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
  end
end
```

and require utilities.rb in spec/spec_helper.rb like this

```
require "support/utilities.rb"

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

end
```

Answer (score -1):

add this to  the top static_pages_spec.rb

include ApplicationHelper